# Como hacer medida para obtener el total de pedidos en el mes de su primera compra - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Buen día compañeros les presento el caso que necesito obtener el total de pedidos del cliente en el mes de su primera compra, para esto necesito obtener el mes de la primera compra y de acuerdo a eso obtener en la tabla de ordenes cuantos pedidos realizo ese día.
Tengo una solución hecha pero lo que hice fue a través de tablas calculadas y esto no es dinámica respecto a la segmentación de fecha.

Por ejemplo esta formula obtiene el id del cliente y la fecha de su primer pedido

```
TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente = GROUPBY('Sales Order','Sales Order'[cliente id],"Fecha",MINX(CURRENTGROUP(),'Sales Order'[DATEUTCMINUS5]))
```

Entonces obtengo el total de pedidos que hizo el cliente con esta formula:

```
total = COUNTROWS(FILTER(CALCULATETABLE('Sales Order',ALLEXCEPT('Sales Order','Sales Order'[cliente id])),'Sales Order'[cliente id]=TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente[Sales Order_cliente ID]))
```

Y con esta formula obtengo el total de pedidos en el mes

```
TotalMes = COUNTROWS(FILTER(CALCULATETABLE('Sales Order',ALLEXCEPT('Sales Order','Sales Order'[cliente id])),'Sales Order'[cliente id]=TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente[Sales Order_cliente id] && Month('Sales Order'[DATEUTCMINUS5])>=MONTH(TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente[Fecha]) && MONTH('Sales Order'[DATEUTCMINUS5])<=MONTH(TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente[Fecha]) && YEAR('Sales Order'[DATEUTCMINUS5])=YEAR(TablaFechaPrimerPedidoCliente[Fecha])))
```

Para obtener esta tabla calculada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando obtengo la tabla calculada la uso para sumar los valores de total y totalmes y mostrarla en tarjetas, pero el valor es obtenido respecto a los datos y cuando uso el selector de fechas no se puede obtener la tabla calculada dinámicamente.

Agradecería que me puedan dar una ida de como podría hacer esto usando medidas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

aquí una posible solución, espero te sirva!

[image: Tabla de Prueba]

medida para obtener ventas del primer mes:

```
Ventas Primer Mes = 
var primerMes = MONTH(MIN(Tabla[FECHA COMPRA]))
return
CALCULATE( COUNT(Tabla[ID COMPRA]) , MONTH(Tabla[FECHA COMPRA]) = primerMes )
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]